# Jquery and Fancybox repeat Gallery

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

HI everyone

I hope you can help me, I have a problem with a requirement, I need to make a list of images that go to cycle.

I have this website, here I have some business cards and I need the images to be repeated after the end of the first cycle and continue like a loop.

here I leave the website, look that the list has a final.

http://tradelinks.com.au/index.php?service=painters

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there is a `cyclic` parameter you can pass when initiating the fancybox which should allow this.   By default it is set to false so you will need to set it to true.

Example:

```
$("a#inline").fancybox({
        'cyclic': true
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

New facybox Version 2
there is a loop parameter you can pass when initiating the fancybox which should allow this. By default it is set to true so you will need not to set it to true.
$("a#inline").fancybox();

Comment: sorry downvote because you answer looks a lot like the accepted answer posted which was posted very long ago. you don't properly show the code with the parameter you specify and your last sentence is wrong 'default set to true so set it to true'....

Comment: Well the last sentence is technically correct: looping IS the default behavior in Fancybox2, and so you'd need to set it to false to change the default behavior. But you're right that doesn't answer the question. The more accurate answer now would be to use Fancybox2 & it's default looping behavior...